# Select n rows from group

Tags: python, pandas

I have data of the form:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'group':['a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],
                   'ref':['a1','a2','a3','b1','b2','b3','b4'],
                   'samps':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2]})

df


  group ref  samps
0     a  a1      1
1     a  a2      1
2     a  a3      1
3     b  b1      2
4     b  b2      2
5     b  b3      2
6     b  b4      2
```

For each `group` I want to randomly flag `samps` of the `ref` cols.

Expected output would be something like:

```
  group ref  samps  sampled
0     a  a1      1        1
1     a  a2      1        0
2     a  a3      1        0
3     b  b1      2        0
4     b  b2      2        1
5     b  b3      2        0
6     b  b4      2        1
```

So `2` from `group` `b` have been flagged, and `1` from `group` `a`.

How can I do this in `pandas`?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is determining the sampling? Why do you have 2 from `b` and 1 from `a`?

Comment: The samps column determined the number of samples that should be drawn from each group.

Comment: @FHTMitchell: I'm triying to use np.random.choice on the ref col to determine those "sampled" and then joining that back on

Comment: @Dan Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with `np.random.choice` after `groupby`, then we just assign the value by the `index`

```
l=[np.random.choice(y.index.values,y['samps'].iloc[0],replace=False) for _, y in df.groupby('group')]
df['sampled']=0
l=np.concatenate(np.array(l))#flatten to one array
df.loc[l,'sampled']=1
df
Out[341]: 
  group ref  samps  sampled
0     a  a1      1        0
1     a  a2      1        0
2     a  a3      1        1
3     b  b1      2        0
4     b  b2      2        1
5     b  b3      2        1
6     b  b4      2        0
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I think you need replace=False in the np.random.choice call, otherwise it might repeat the choice